# ImportError: cannot import name 'path'

Tags: python-3.x, module

I've written a small piece of code to get the number of files in a directory.
I installed the path module as well, but still i'm getting the error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'path' while running the code.
```

Code:

```
root@Anon:# cat cleanup.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3


from path import path
d=('/home/us3r/sample/')
num_files=len(d.files())
print(num_files)
```

I'm executing the code from the Linux terminal as below:

```
./cleanup.py
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: `path` is in [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Comment: And.... you're not even.... using it...

Comment: You don't even need `path`. just `os`: `len(os.listdir(d))`

Comment: [I belive this answer might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)